# I want to know how to use when without else in an enum class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, enum-class

I learned to use `enum class` to constantize the constants involved.
I also learned that using `when` when using enum class is very effective.
I think I heard that you may not use `else`.

Case1 may not use `else` in isMovable. However, we still have to use the `else` in fromConditionOf() and the `when` is redundant twice.

Am I misunderstanding something?
Should I use `else` when using `enum class`?

Case 0 is the code when no `enum class` is used

To briefly explain the code, when the car gets a random value (0-9), it stops if it's 0-3, and moves forward if it's 4-9.

Case 0:

```
data class Car(
    val name: CarName,
) {
    init {
        require(name.isNotBlank()) { "[ERROR] Name is empty or blank" }
        require(name.length <= 5) { "[ERROR] Car names longer than five letters" }
    }

    fun move(randomValue: Int) =
        when (randomValue) {
            in 4..9 -> true
            in 0..3 -> false
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("[ERROR] When a random value is invalid")
        }
}
```

Case 1:

```
enum class Movement(val range: IntRange) {
    STOP(0..3),
    GO(4..9);

    companion object {
        fun fromConditionOf(randomValue: Int): Movement =
            when (randomValue) {
                in STOP.range -> STOP
                in GO.range -> GO
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("[ERROR] When a random value is invalid")
            }
    }
}

data class Car(
    val name: String,
) {
    init {
        require(name.isNotBlank()) { "[ERROR] Name is empty or blank" }
        require(name.length <= 5) { "[ERROR] Car names longer than five letters" }
    }

    fun isMovable(randomValue: Int): Boolean =
        when (Movement.fromConditionOf(randomValue)) {
            Movement.STOP -> false
            Movement.GO -> true
        }
}
```

Case2:

```
enum class Movement(val range: IntRange) {
    STOP(0..3),
    GO(4..9);

    companion object {
        fun fromConditionOf(randomValue: Int): Boolean =
            when (randomValue) {
                in STOP.range -> false
                in GO.range -> true
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("[ERROR] When a random value is invalid")
            }
    }
}

data class Car(
    val name: String,
) {
    init {
        require(name.isNotBlank()) { "[ERROR] Name is empty or blank" }
        require(name.length <= 5) { "[ERROR] Car names longer than five letters" }
    }

    fun isMovable(randomValue: Int): Boolean =
        Movement.fromConditionOf(randomValue)
}
```

Comment: the redundant `else` are not actually redundant. You're running a when clause through an Int value. so there are other int values than those that you have given a specific handling for. Case 1 Car.isMovable is actually running the when through the enum and you can see that no else is needed because there are finite values.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
So can we say that case1 used `enum class` and `when` well?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: It was awkward to use `when` twice because it felt like it was redundant. I think I misunderstood. thank you!

Comment: you'd be better not having the enum in the example and just running the integer through the when clause directly. that'll be more efficient. but for the process of learning and using enums with when it fine.

Comment: Thank you so much.

I really have one last question and it's a simple one!
Since the Movement enum class is a constant class created for use in Car, would it be better to put it inside the Car data class?
I don't know if it's a good idea to nest classes because I don't understand the concept of classes.

Comment: The question I'd ask myself here is "Is it only to be used in Car?"

Comment: I understand what you mean. If it's only used in the car, I guess it belongs inside! It is only used to control the movement of the Car.

Comment: exactly. There's no need to give it greater scope than absolutely necessary.

Comment: i really appreciate it! i respect u. I wanna be an android dev!